How can I make a tuple of types that can be accessed by index without pack indexing?
Using C++26's pack indexing, you can create a simple tuple of types like so:
template <typename... Ts>
struct type_tuple {
    template <unsigned Index>
    using get = Ts...[Index];
};

using T = type_tuple<int, float, double>::get<1>; // float

How can this be replicated in earlier C++ versions?

You can use std::tuple_element. This will work in all C++ versions supporting parameter packs:
template <typename... Ts>
struct type_tuple {

template <std::size_t Index>
using get = typename std::tuple_element<Index, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

};


Thanks. You can use tuple_element_t to make it shorter.

@HeliumHydride You're welcome! You can't use tuple_element_t in C++11 though. It was added in C++14.

@TedLyngmo you can manually define it (and any other _t and _v alias) in C++11

@RemyLebeau Yes, the _t helpers can be added but _v would require variable templates (C++14).

If you are interested how it is done inside std::tuple, then it is as simple as this:
template <std::size_t Index, typename ...T>
struct NthType;
//{};

template <typename T0, typename ...T>
struct NthType<0, T0, T...>
{
    using Type = T0;
};

template <std::size_t Index, typename T0, typename ...T>
struct NthType<Index, T0, T...>
{
    using Type = typename NthType<Index-1, T...>::Type; // skip one type, decrease index
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct type_tuple {
    template <unsigned Index>
    using get = typename NthType<Index, Ts...>::Type;
};

So:

Define helper class NthType<Index, T...>
Specialize for Index = 0: NthType<0, T0, T...>::Type == T0
Make linear search for Nth type: NthType<Idx, T0, T...>::Type == NthType<Idx - 1, T...>

Note, that in last point we skip first type from pack, and decrease the index.
In many libraries (including std lib implementations) there are also specialization for Index==1 and Index==2 just for spead up.
I am not sure that, but in some compilers I can imagine there are builtin functions to get nth type from a pack - similar to C++26 way.
Before C++11 (before introduction of variadic templates) - there was just 50 or so specialization of such NthType - so it works up to Index==50 (or so...)

This avoids reliance on std::tuple, but I'm using the accepted version. Thank you.

Of course std::tuple is a best choice here. I just wanted to explain how it works under the hood. BTW, if you have possibility to use boost - there are quire good type-list manipulating libraries like mp11 or hana. But for this case - std::tuple is just enough,
